# issues with php mail function 'to' field

Tags: php

Amateur question, I know but could someone please let me know the correct syntax for inputting variables in the "$to = " section when using php's mail function.  When I used the below format, I got an error.  I know its possible to input the email addresses as constants like "$to = abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com", but I want to use variables.

Thanks in advance!

```
    $to = '$user1', '$user2';
    $subject = 'Congratulations! You have a match!';
    $message = 'Someone who you liked likes you too! Log in to find out who';
    $headers = 'From: info@xyy.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@xyy.com' . "\r\n" .
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$to = '$user1', '$user2';
```

to this

```
$to = "$user1,$user2";
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy as

```
$to = "$user1, $user2";
```

Please ensure you have validated e-mail addresses, e.g. by using

```
$to = filter_var($user1, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) . ', ' . filter_var($user2, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

which implements a little security.

Answer (score 0):

It accepts a single comma separed string.

```
$to="$user1,$user";
```

[Phpmail docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)